# How to ignore white space in the hash key while getting value using powershell

Tags: powershell, hash, azure-powershell

I am trying to get the value of the hash key. It is working fine when there is an exact match of the key. But as any space found int the key it gives an error.
Working fine :

```
$tagHash = (Get-AzResourceGroup -Name "twmstgmsnp").Tags
$datevalue = $tagHash.GetEnumerator() | ? Key -eq Date | % Value
Write-Host "Resource Group Date tag : " $datevalue.Replace(' ','')
```

I am trying to ignore space in key :

```
$tagHash = (Get-AzResourceGroup -Name "twmstgmsnp").Tags
$datevalue = $tagHash.GetEnumerator() | ? Key -eq 'Date'.Replace(' ','') | % Value
Write-Host "Resource Group Date tag : " $datevalue.Replace(' ','')
```

Error: Actually my $datevalue is null because not getting value.

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal working example? Nobody will be able to run this code snippet. We can only guess how your data structures will look like. I can only say for sure that `'Date'.Replace(' ','')` will delete spaces inside the string `Date`, which do not exist of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand your meaning, you want to get the value e.g. when the key is like `D   a t e`, if so, you could use the command below.

```
$tagHash = (Get-AzResourceGroup -Name "<group-name>").Tags
$datevalue = $tagHash.GetEnumerator() | ? {($_.Key).ToString().Replace(' ','') -eq 'Date'} | % Value
Write-Host "Resource Group Date tag : " $datevalue.Replace(' ','')
```

[image]

The tag is like below in the portal:

[image]

Comment: can you help why this statement not getting any value -> $ownervalue = $tagHash.GetEnumerator() | ? {($_.Key).ToString().Replace(' ','') -eq 'CreatedBy'} | % Value

My hash contains the keys -> PURPOSE Created By

Comment: @rAJ You mean the key is `PURPOSE Created By`? If so, it should be `$tagHash.GetEnumerator() | ? {($_.Key).ToString().Replace(' ','') -eq 'PURPOSECreatedBy'} | % Value`.

Comment: no they are two separate keys. Question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541666/getting-null-hash-value-while-matching-key-using-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

```bsh
$data = @{ "aaa" = "bbb"; "c c c" = "ddd" }

$search = "ccc"
$matches = $data.Keys | where-object { $_.Replace(" ", "") -eq $search }
# c c c

$values = $data[$matches]
# ddd
```

Note that you *could* get multiple matches so you'll need to work out which value you want in that case - e.g.:

```bsh
$data = @{ "aaa" = "bbb"; "c c c" = "ddd"; "ccc" = "eee" }

$search = "ccc"
$matches = $data.Keys | where-object { $_.Replace(" ", "") -eq $search }
# ccc
# c c c

$values = $data[$matches]
# eee
# ddd
```