# Getting null hash value while matching key using powershell

Tags: powershell, hash, azure-powershell

I am trying to get the value of the key by matching key name(ignoring the white and character case).

**Code :**

```
$tagHash = (Get-AzResourceGroup -Name "twmstgmsnp").Tags
Write-Host "Resource Group tags key : " $tagHash.Keys
Write-Host "Resource Group tags value : " $tagHash.Values
$ownervalue = $tagHash.GetEnumerator() | ? {($_.Key).ToString().Replace(' ','') -eq 'CreatedBy'} | % Value
Write-Host "Resource Group CREATEDBY tag : " $ownervalue
```

**Result :**

Resource Group tags key :  `PURPOSE` `Created By`

Resource Group tags value :  `QA MS Team2 env` `Shubham Mishra`

Resource Group CREATEDBY tag :

[image]

**Note : It should always fetch the value if the key should have the text 'createdby'. Whether the key is 'Created By', 'Created By ', 'CREATEDBY', 'CREATED BY'. It should ignore the key white space and case.**

Comment: Does `? {$_.Key -like "*Created By*"}` work?

Comment: Your Group Tag has `Created By`, but you are checking to see if it is equal to `CreatedBy`. Note the lack of space.

Comment: Yes, this is my requirement. It should match the text while ignoring any space or case.

Comment: Your script works on my side, could you make sure the tags are correct in the portal?https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxZNT.png

Comment: updated question with tag image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you can get the exact name for the key easiest by replacing all whitespace from it first and next compare it to `CreatedBy`.
No need for the `GetEnumerator()` method, simply get the key name from the `.Keys` array:

```
$ownerKey = $tags.Keys | Where-Object { ($_ -replace '\s') -eq 'CreatedBy'}
Write-Host "Resource Group CREATEDBY Tag   : $ownerKey"
Write-Host "Resource Group CREATEDBY Value : $($tags[$ownerKey])"
```

Output:

```
Resource Group CREATEDBY Tag   :  Created By
Resource Group CREATEDBY Value :  Shubham Mishra
```

<sup>By default the `-eq` operator works case-insensitive. If you need case-sensitive comparison somewhere else, use `-ceq`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you read what your 4th and 5th lines are doing in plain text, it might make more sense where things have gone wrong.

Line 4:
Put all this in a variable: Get the enumerator from `$tagHash` and then get all the Keys like "Created By" and then for each match Value.

```
$ownervalue = $tagHash.GetEnumerator() | ? {($_.Key).ToString().Replace(' ','') -eq 'CreatedBy'} | % Value
```

Line 5:
Write the variable to the host window.

```
Write-Host "Resource Group CREATEDBY tag : " $ownervalue
```

This is what you want it to say in plain text:
Get the enumerator from `$tagHash` and then get all the Keys like "Created By" and then for each match write the value to the host window.

```
$tagHash.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { $_.Key -like '*Created*By*'} | For-Each
{
    Write-Host "Resource Group CREATEDBY tag : " $_.Value
}
```